# How to reorder my primary key rows using Java/Android and SQLite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a first activity where I create a database and insert some data. In my second activity I remove datas from my DB and the thing that I would like to know is how to reorder my row ID-s to be in consecutive order.

For example, my DB after deleting some rows looks like this:
--------1-------------Question1-------------Answer1---------0
--------3-------------Question2-------------Answer2---------3
--------5-------------Question3-------------Answer3---------5

After exiting my activity, I want to look like this:
--------1-------------Question1-------------Answer1---------0
--------2-------------Question2-------------Answer2---------3
--------3-------------Question3-------------Answer3---------5

Tried  onDestroy() function using this

> @Override
>
> protected void onDestroy() {
>
> ```
>   super.onDestroy();
>
>   if (mDbHelper != null) {
>       for(int i=0; i<mDbHelper.countRows(); i++){
>           try{
>               mDbHelper.updateDate(Integer.toString(i++), ggQuestions[i], ggAnswers[i], pozz++);
>           }catch(Exception ex){}
>       }
>
>       mDbHelper.close();
>   }
> ```
>
> }

where mDbHelper is my Database, my primary key is String (that's why using integer to string) and my updateDate sql function looks like this:

> ```
>   mDb.execSQL("UPDATE flagtable SET _id="+_superID+", answer='"+answ+"', position="+
>               Integer.toString(pozz)+" WHERE question='"+quest+"'");
> ```

I get this error: Failure 19 primary key must be unique when executing UPDATE

Comment: Solved by deleting all records from database and than re-inserting them...this is awful because I had to save them in seperate arrays, for bigger databases wouldn't be indicated.  Anyone has a more simple method?

Comment: I don't think you can other than with a new table, but I upvoted because I would like to know also.  I do know that inside your database, there is a table sqlite_sequence.  I may play around with that after work.

Comment: Why do they need to be consecutive?  Not generally done.  If you have the need for some kind of surrogate consecutive order, I'd probably do it with a second column that can be updated in-place without changing the primary key of every row (and having to update any references to those primary keys in other tables...)

Comment: I need them to be in consecutive order, because after exiting my second activity I enter my first activity and do more inserting...